# How can i make first commit, the plugin will become public?

Tags: plugins, wordpress, submit

I am trying to submit an plugin on wordpress.org plugin directory. It has been already approved but i seen this "This plugin is approved and awaiting data upload but not visible to the public yet. Once you make your first commit, the plugin will become public". Now i didn't find out how can i make public this. Please anyone kindly help me about how can i make public my plugin.
This is my [plugin link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/progression-contact-form/) but i think you can not seen this.

Comment: Once you do your first `svn` to the `/trunk` directory with a valid `readme.txt` file, your plugin will be live. Just [**follow the instructions**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/svn/) carefully.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not programming related.

Comment: Follow this [tutorial](http://1manfactory.com/wordpress-plugins-upload-with-subversion-tortoise-and-windows-tutorial/). This one helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative method to svn, if you are hosting the plugin on Github you can use the [Ship](http://ship.getherbert.com/) application.